# How to create a /system/bin link on android

Tags: android, shell, daemon

I would like to create a link to /system/bin on the root file system of Android M OS.
The link is created if I do this command :

```
mount -o remount,rw /   
ln -s /system/bin /bin  
mount -o remount,ro / 

root@nexbox:/ # ls -l                       
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 acct
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:04 bin -> /system/bin
drwxr-xr-x root     root              1970-01-01 01:00 boot
drwxrwx--- system   cache             2017-06-15 02:08 cache
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1970-01-01 01:00 charger -> /sbin/healthd
dr-x------ root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 config
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 d -> /sys/kernel/debug
```

But when I reboot the device the link is disappeared. I tried to do a daemon like this in /system/etc/init.d

```
# crond has "/bin/sh" hardcoded
mount -o remount,rw -t auto /
ln -s /system/bin /bin
mount -o remount,ro -t auto /
```

It doesn't work 
What am I missing?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is because folders/files in the root directory are created/mounted in your ramdisk and not your system partition. You need to modify the `/init.rc` file on your system to create the symlink by adding `symlink /system/bin /bin` to the end of it.

In order to do this you will need to:

Copy boot partition to boot image file.

Unpack boot image file.

Unpack ramdisk.

Modify init.rc.

Repack ramdisk and boot image.

Write modified boot image back to boot partition of the device.